# Regex to match one or more digits

Tags: python, regex

I got dataset like that (it's opened as str from file):

```
MF8='out1mf8':'constant',[1944.37578865883]
MF9='out1mf9':'constant',[2147.79853787502]
MF10='out1mf10':'constant',[565.635908155949]
MF11='out1mf11':'constant',[0]
MF12='out1mf12':'constant',[0]
```

I need this values in brackets, so a created regex:

```
outmfPattern = 'out\dmf\d'
```

and used:

```
re.findall(outmfPattern, f)
```

It's working nice until `mf = 9`. Does anybody has idea how to handle with this?

Comment: `'out\dmf\d+'` The `+` specifies one or more matches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's break down your regex `out\dmf\d`:

- `out` matches the sequence `'out'`
- `\d` matches a digit
- `mf` match the sequence `'mf'`
- `\d` matches a digit

If you want to match something like `out1mf11`, you'll need to look for *2* digits at the end.

You can use `out\dmf\d+`, or, if you want to match *only 1 or 2* digits at the end, `out\dmf\d{1,2}`.

---

```
In [373]: re.findall('out\dmf\d+', text)
Out[373]: ['out1mf8', 'out1mf9', 'out1mf10', 'out1mf11', 'out1mf12']
```

---

Furthermore, if you want to add brackets to those search items, you probably should look at `re.sub` instead:

```
In [377]: re.sub('(out\dmf\d+)', r'(\1)', text)
Out[377]: "MF8='(out1mf8)':'constant',[1944.37578865883] MF9='(out1mf9)':'constant',[2147.79853787502] MF10='(out1mf10)':'constant',[565.635908155949] MF11='(out1mf11)':'constant',[0] MF12='(out1mf12)':'constant',[0]"
```

`re.sub` replaces the captured groups with the same enclosed in parens.